# canvas draw - change rotation axis without clearing old state

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm using html5 canvas to create a simple 3d polygon program. the program allows to change the rotation of each axis - x,y,z. on the event of change x/y/z angle, a corresponding call to the drawing function is done. the problem is every time I make a new call to the draw function it clears the older position and the result is it jumps. basically each function works on its own but they do not work together.

example code:

```
var Perspective = function(rotate){
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
//clear
...
switch(rotate){
case "x" : {
var transform = Mat3.rotationX(Math.radians(rotateX.getValue())); //rotation x
break;
}
case "y" : {
var transform = Mat3.rotationY(Math.radians(rotateY.getValue())); //rotation y
break;
}
case "z" : {
var transform = Mat3.rotationZ(Math.radians(rotateZ.getValue())); //rotation Z
}
...
draw(...settings..)
}
```

set a listener to each slider change event (also for Y and Z). AngleX makes the call to Perspective, passing the string "x" as rotate param.

```
var angleX = $('#AngleX').slider()
            .on('slide change', AngleX)
            .data('slider');
```

how can i make the changes if different axis more dynamic ?

Comment: Your question is slightly confusing and does not include enough information to debug without making a large number of assumptions.  Can you recreate your issue in jsfiddle.com and post it.

Comment: I have uploaded it to a server :  http://rafaelbar.byethost11.com/3d/ , try to use only the rotate sliders and you can see the movement is not continuous. it is a bit hard to explain much easer to try ..

Comment: No one help this person he is trying to infect people computers with malwar

Comment: what are you talking about  ?..

Comment: The link you provided was flagged for spreading malware

Comment: that nonsense..! https://www.virustotal.com/en/url/36545b688e049c791aa5df3b3b990de62545f6bcc92b7a55e48d5f0d10e84a30/analysis/1454684519/

Comment: its a simple hosting i'm using , no malware !! not trying to infect anything . I'm a security analyst i know what i'm talking about.

Comment: anyway i'v solved it no thanks to you @QBM5 .. the switch case was a mistake, you must multiply all axis like this : var transform = Mat3.rotationX(-Math.radians(rotateY.getValue()))
   .multiply(Mat3.rotationY(Math.radians(rotateX.getValue())));

Answer (score 0):

anyway i'v solved it no thanks to you QBM5 .. the switch case was a mistake, i had to multiply all axis transformation matrixs like this :

```
 var transform = Mat3.rotationX(-Math.radians(rotateY.getValue())) .multiply(Mat3.rotationY(Math.radians(rotateX.getValue())));
```